# Ubuntu 12.10 recognizes wireless, but does not connect (Intel Centrino -N 1000)

Tags: 12.10, drivers, intel-wireless

here is my problem, I just installed Ubuntu 12.10 and everything went great, but when I try to connect to any wireless network it keeps connecting and after a while it says "Wireless Network Disconnected - Your are now offline"

Thank you so much.

This is some information about my card and other stuff, I really don't know much about the subject:

**ifconfig:**

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 64:31:50:7d:a2:c8  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:224 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:224 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:18400 (18.4 KB)  TX bytes:18400 (18.4 KB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 8c:a9:82:06:2c:2a  
          inet6 addr: fe80::8ea9:82ff:fe06:2c2a/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:108 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:29068 (29.0 KB)
```

**iwconfig:**

```
eth0      no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

wlan0     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:"60200516"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.462 GHz  Access Point: EC:55:F9:38:3B:A3   
          Bit Rate=1 Mb/s   Tx-Power=14 dBm   
          Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=70/70  Signal level=-27 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0
```

**lspci:**

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor DRAM Controller (rev 02)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 02)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset HECI Controller (rev 06)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset USB2 Enhanced Host Controller (rev 05)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset High Definition Audio (rev 05)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev 05)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev 05)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset USB2 Enhanced Host Controller (rev 05)
00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile PCI Bridge (rev a5)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Mobile 5 Series Chipset LPC Interface Controller (rev 05)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset 4 port SATA AHCI Controller (rev 05)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset SMBus Controller (rev 05)
00:1f.6 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset Thermal Subsystem (rev 05)
01:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168B PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet controller (rev 03)
02:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N 1000
ff:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor QuickPath Architecture Generic Non-core Registers (rev 05)
ff:00.1 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor QuickPath Architecture System Address Decoder (rev 05)
ff:02.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor QPI Link 0 (rev 05)
ff:02.1 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor QPI Physical 0 (rev 05)
ff:02.2 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor Reserved (rev 05)
ff:02.3 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor Reserved (rev 05)
```

**lsusb:**

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor DRAM Controller (rev 02)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 02)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset HECI Controller (rev 06)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset USB2 Enhanced Host Controller (rev 05)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset High Definition Audio (rev 05)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev 05)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev 05)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset USB2 Enhanced Host Controller (rev 05)
00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile PCI Bridge (rev a5)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Mobile 5 Series Chipset LPC Interface Controller (rev 05)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset 4 port SATA AHCI Controller (rev 05)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset SMBus Controller (rev 05)
00:1f.6 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset Thermal Subsystem (rev 05)
01:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168B PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet controller (rev 03)
02:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N 1000
ff:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor QuickPath Architecture Generic Non-core Registers (rev 05)
ff:00.1 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor QuickPath Architecture System Address Decoder (rev 05)
ff:02.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor QPI Link 0 (rev 05)
ff:02.1 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor QPI Physical 0 (rev 05)
ff:02.2 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor Reserved (rev 05)
ff:02.3 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor Reserved (rev 05)
```

**rfkill_list:**

```
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: hp-bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
3: hp-wifi: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Comment: Please post the output of all output of `sudo tail -f /var/log/syslog` in a terminal *while you attempt to connect to the network*. Network Manager logs to syslog and will probably give you/us some more clues as to why you're not getting connected. I've seen two reasons in my case: DHCP timeout, AP does not let the client associate. Your wireless card should be supported quite well.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://askubuntu.com/questions/230412/wireless-not-working-with-intel-corporation-centrino-wireless-n-1000 (open)

Comment: Have you connected via Ethernet, and searched for drivers?

Comment: Fix for **11.10** here: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1941350

Comment: Hi @david6 I already read http://askubuntu.com/questions/230412/wireless-not-working-with-intel-corporation-centrino-wireless-n-1000 but it didn't help me :( I also try http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1941350 but still doesn't help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found the solution, FINALLY! It was [here](http://www.kubuntuforums.net/showthread.php?60746-Unable-to-use-wirelles-network-in-Kubuntu-12-10&s=f82042d7035bfb6b39258e135a395c9c) (Post #5)

What I did was, in "Edit Connections..." delete all the existing connections and then add the wireless network manually. After reboot it keeps working :)

Thank you all for your replies! They helped a lot

Answer (score 0):

It could be your network router kicking you off. Have you checked to see if there are any IP address conflicts, or if you have the correct network ID? Here is how to check.

If you have another computer connected to the network running windows (7) open the network and sharing window. in the window look at your active network. click the network connection and look for your SSID, this is the network ID. Under details in the same window you should see the IPv4 address. It usually is something like 192.168.1.100. When you go back to your Ubuntu computer, click the network icon in the upper right, and select connection information to display your IP address. The number should be similar, but the last numbers have to be different (e.g. windows IP 192.168.1.100, Linux IP 192.168.1.102) If they match you need to change one. To check the network ID click the network icon and select edit connections. Select your wireless network, click edit, and the SSID should be displayed. It must match the one on the windows computer. If the Ip's are different and the SSID's match, then you have a different issue that I am not familiar with.

Comment: Thank for replying, but how do I know if there is a IP address conflicts? or if I have the correct network ID?

Comment: see second answer, mine was to long:-)

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug report report for this issue (**Ubuntu 12.10**):

[NM fails to connect Wi-Fi; dhclient works -- Intel Centrino Wireless-N 1000 iwlwifi](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1017738)

This suggests that Ubuntu is failing to issue **iwconfig** for this device / driver.

---

**Possible workaround: (from Post #40)**

> [jerrylamos (jerrylamos) wrote on 2012-11-24:](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1017738/comments/40)
>
> Workaround since this bug is even worse with 3.7.0-3:
>
> ```
> Startup Applications
> Add
> Title: Connect
> command: ~/wl
> ```
>
> where wl is
>
> ```
> #!/bin/bash
> sudo iwconfig wlan0 essid LAUREL   { <-- your SSID }
> sudo dhclient wlan0
> exit 0
> ```
>
> Has worked O.K. for three boots so far.
>
> Why can't Ubuntu issue the iwconfig??

Comment: This solution didn't work for me

Answer (score 0):

I found a different workaround with `ndiswrapper`, a tool that injects Windows XP's drivers in Ubuntu.  You can download it from http://sourceforge.net/projects/ndiswrapper/files/latest/download?source=files
Once you have downloaded the .tar.gz file, unpack it on the Desktop and follow all the instructions in `INSTALL` file.

There is a passage where it asks you to write "`ndiswrapper -l`" in the Terminal, and it says you should get "`driver present, hardware present`". If you get something like "`device (2001:3308) present (alternate driver: rtl8192cu)`", add the name of the alternate driver (in this case "`rtl8192cu`") to `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`
To do it, just type in Terminal

```
sudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```

and add "`blacklist rtl8192cu`" (`rtl8192cu` is the name of the driver I have, you should put the name of the driver YOU have) in a new line. Then just save and reboot. 
If you followed correctly all the instructions in `INSTALL` file, the wifi key will use the Windows driver instead of the Linux driver.